# How to activate elements at different points of scroll down page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to 'activate' or 'click' on different elements as the user scrolls down the page. I.e. as the user scrolls down the page, element 1 should deactivate and element 2 should activate. Then 2 should deactivate and 3 should activate. It is important that these elements get 'clicked' and not just have a CSS change.

It works on the first one (it clicks .no2 and the tab activates) but then as you scroll down, .no3 and .n04 don't click, so I assume once the first if statement is true, it no longer checks the next if statement.

Please see my code here:

```
<script>

$(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 200) {
            $('.no2').triggerHandler('click');
        }

        if (scroll >= 250) {
            $('.no3').triggerHandler('click');
        }

        if (scroll >= 300) {
            $('.no4').triggerHandler('click');
        }

    });
    });

 </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/o4vsbdw7. Note that `scroll` fires for every pixel which is why you see the repeated items in the console. Debug your code to see if `triggerHandler()` is even working outside of the `scroll` event.

Answer (score -1):

You can use libraries to help you achieve it easily try `AOS`

https://wesbos.com/javascript/06-serious-practice-exercises/scroll-events-and-intersection-observer

Else you can use `Intesection Observer`

https://wesbos.com/javascript/06-serious-practice-exercises/scroll-events-and-intersection-observer